# How do I show that the set is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two spaces which are homeomorphic.
If one of them is compact, how do I show that the other is also compact?

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Cover one, pull it back, reduce finitely, push it forward.

Answer (score 1):

Because if $X$ is compact and $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous, then $f(X)$ is compact.